# Scroll bars with android v7 StaggeredGridLayoutManager,RecycleView

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

How to show scroll bars with StaggeredGridLayoutManager in recycle view. I have enable vertical scroll bars as true in recycle view but no scrollbar is visible.

Does any one faces the similar issue?